# how I can Use two table in a time with Xamarin Android

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin

I have one connection for each table in a database like the below, How Can I use Two Table in a time?? My Main trouble is how connect to Two Table in  a time to use them. Please somebody tell me about that
part of My code is:

```
    public bool createDataBase()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var connection = new 
            SQLiteConnection(System.IO.Path.Combine(folder, "Plans.db")))
            {
                connection.CreateTable<Plan>();
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (SQLiteException ex)
        {

            Log.Info("SQLiteEx", ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }

    public bool createDataBase2()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(System.IO.Path.Combine(folder, "PlanDoned.db")))
            {
                connection.CreateTable<Plan>();
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (SQLiteException ex)
        {

            Log.Info("SQLiteEx", ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }


    public bool insertIntoTablePlanDoned(Plan plan)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var connection = new 
            SQLiteConnection(System.IO.Path.Combine(folder, "PlanDoned.db")))
            {
                //connection.Query<Plan>("UPDATE Plan SET PlanName=?,PlanDate=?,PlanDesc=? where Id=?", plan.PlanName, plan.PlanDate, plan.PlanDesc, plan.Id);
                //return true;
                connection.Query<Plan>("insert into PlanDoned select * from Plans where Id=?", plan.Id);
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (SQLiteException ex)
        {
            Log.Info("SQLiteEx", ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you making two databases with the same table in them?

Answer (score 0):

use `ATTACH DATABASE 'Database2Path' As 'Database2Name';`
Then use both Database1 and Database2 in the same query i.e.:

```
INSERT INTO Database2Name.Table SELECT Column1, Column2 FROM Database1.Table
```